# Serialization and Deserialization in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have tried storing classes on files in java.
Something like shown [in this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)

To my knowledge java converts the class into a byte steam and stores it.

I am relatively new to flutter and don't know much about dart, I've searched a lot but not able to find how to do the same in flutter.

I was able to find only JSON serialization for flutter, would like to know how to serialize my class to a byte stream and save to file and then retrieve deserialized class back.

P.S.: I think java serialization stores data in other format than JSON, if it's not the case and if java does store it in JSON format then I am sorry for the inconvenience caused by me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Dart doesn't have a built in serialization mechanism the way Java does. This means you have to choose some approach for serialization.

[This doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) covers some options using pure JSON serializations that may meet your needs.

If you are already using the [`built_value`](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart) package, classes which implement `Built` can be serialized easily with a little extra boilerplate. The readme covers this and links to some articles and tutorials with more guidance.

Comment: Dart _does_ have the same feature as Java, but it is not enabled in Flutter. It is enabled on angular though.

Comment: Thank You, the documentation is really helpful.